# How to detect full screen gesture mode in Mi devices programmatically

Tags: android, fullscreen, xiaomi

I am writing an Android application that needs to calculate the height of screen to display content correctly. But the height I got in Mi devices (Mi 9 SE) wasn't correct when switching to full screen gesture mode.
How can I get the real height of the screen, or check if user turned on full screen gesture mode in Mi devices?

I have tried these suggestions.

1. [How to detect full screen gesture mode in android Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689210/how-to-detect-full-screen-gesture-mode-in-android-q)
2. [Android: detect navigation bar visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775694/android-detect-navigation-bar-visibility)
3. [Check for navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092431/check-for-navigation-bar)

Comment: Why Xiaomi developers do not use the standard methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and experimenting, I have found the only solution: [How to detect full screen gesture mode in android Q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56792591/7818051).

Instead of using `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener()` function, I just have to create a `WindowInsets` instance for the current context, then check the `getSystemGestureInsets()` for each edges. This is how I implemented to make a React Native's native module.

If you need a listener to detect every changes, the solution above has done well on Android app. If you want this listener for React Native, you might want to find another approach, since I haven't made it work.

Comment: Well, this would work only on android Q or higher Xiaomi devices

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhary. Absolutely. The fullscreen gesture mode is only available for Android Q and higher version, which makes old methods not function correctly.

Comment: But full screen gesture features are available on Xiaomi devices running android O also

Comment: can give this to try. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76872801/1118747

Answer (score 0):

A very simpler answer:
Don't use DisplayMetrics. Just make any view take full width and height of the screen (MATCH_PARENT) then get it's dimensions, it well give accurate numbers.