# Check Visibility of navigation bar in Android

Tags: android, navigation

I have an overlay and want to position it's x or y params accrodingly. I face difficulty with the navigation bar. Few apps use SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION and few don't. So my overlay when placed in the corner works fine when nav buttons are hidden for the app I am putting my overlay and goes beyond the screen when navbar is present.

I am able to detect if nav bar is enabled, but want to know if it is actually appearing on the screen or hidden by the app.

Comment: i think this could help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775694/android-detect-navigation-bar-visibility