# Can I anchor a snackbar to Android native bottom navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-snackbar, snackbar, android-navigation-bar

I want to anchor a snackbar to the Android native bottom navigation bar.

As I saw the documentation:

> Anchoring a Snackbar By default, Snackbars will be anchored to the
>   bottom edge of their parent view. However, you can use the
>   Snackbar#setAnchorView method to make a Snackbar appear above a
>   specific view within your layout, e.g., a FloatingActionButton. This
>   is especially helpful if you would like to place a Snackbar above
>   navigational elements at the bottom of the screen, such as a
>   BottomAppBar or BottomNavigationView.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35426680/311130) on how to get the Android native bottom navigation bar.

```
int id = resources.getIdentifier("config_showNavigationBar", "bool", "android");
        return id > 0 && resources.getBoolean(id);
```

But then, is it just a boolean I can get and no the id of the view itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you need to place your snackbar above your bottom navigation, all you need to do is :

```kotlin
val bottomNavigation: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)
Snackbar.make(it, "Hello World", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAnchorView(bottomNavigation).show()
```

Note: A nice documentation about [Snackbars](https://material.io/develop/android/components/snackbar/) and Android design in general.